# GPUImage saving video in background issue

Tags: gpuimage

I'm having an issue with saving video from a GPUImage videoCamera to the Camera Roll when my app goes into the background. The file is only saved to the camera roll when the app returns to the foreground / is restarted. I'm no doubt making a beginners code error , if anyone can point it out that would be appreciated.

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

if (isRecording){
    [self stopRecording];
};
if (self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window){
    [videoCamera stopCameraCapture];
};
runSynchronouslyOnVideoProcessingQueue(^{
    glFinish();
});
NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
```

and then

```
-(void)stopRecording {
[filterBlend removeTarget:movieWriter];
videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
[movieWriter finishRecording];
NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.mov"];
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[al writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }

}];
isRecording = NO;
NSLog(@"Stop recording");
```

Comment: Does `-finishRecording` complete before your application heads to the background? If you throw a breakpoint or log statement after that, when does it complete? I'd check to make sure that `-writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock:` starts as you are entering the background, and isn't waiting until you return to the foreground.

Comment: Thanks Brad, it was exactly as you diagnosed,and once again thanks for GPUImage, it's incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1):

It was exactly as Brad pointed out in his, as usual, insightful comment, the -writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock:  wasn't completing till after the app returned to the foreground, I solved it by adding

```
self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Background handler called. Not running background tasks anymore.");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
    self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask;
```

Found this solution at http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios